# Java, from a jTable to vectors

Tags: java, jtable

I would like to get the values from a two columns jTable and then put them into two vectors. The following lines contains the correct values:

```
Double.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
Double.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
```

But I think that I was wrong to put them into the vectors. Probably it's a very banal mistake. This is the full code:

```
int nr=jTable1.getRowCount();
double[] x=new double[nr];
double[] y=new double[nr];
for (int i=0;i<nr;i++) {
    x[i]=Double.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
    y[i]=Double.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: how are you creating the jtable (displaying values) ???

Comment: The table with each value has been created via the NetBeans palette.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply take the table model and convert it to a Vector:

`((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).getDataVector();`

The Table Model is a representation of all data stored in the table. Internal, data is stored as a Vector that you can get from the Class.